# Eclipse find references for method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I wanted to find all the callers of the the method "get" for the following class:

```
package com.zzz.zzz.zzz.services;

public final class EMF {
  private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("obamaCareIsGood4U");

  private EMF() {}

  public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
    return emfInstance;
  }
}
```

So I highlited the text "get" and right-clicked References - project. But it returned references to every method called "get", rather than just references to com.zzz.zzz.zzz.services.EMF.get().

Is this an eclipse bug? How do I get Eclipse to show references only to com.zzz.zzz.zzz.services.EMF.get()?

```
Eclipse Platform  Version:
4.2.0.v20120608-135145-9JF7BHV8FyMteji0Oi_ePMz0xuZ8TVo7lV0z0ecb
Build id:
I20120608-1400,

Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.0.0.M3 Build Id: 201207050802
```

Output of reference search:

```
com.google.common.base - guava-12.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\12.0 - PatientCare
com.google.common.base - guava-gwt-12.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava-gwt\12.0 - PatientCare
com.google.gwt.junit.server - gwt-user-2.4.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0 - PatientCare
com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server - gwt-servlet-2.2.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-servlet\2.2.0 - PatientCare
com.google.gwt.resources.rg - gwt-user-2.4.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0 - PatientCare
com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client - gwt-servlet-2.2.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-servlet\2.2.0 - PatientCare
com.google.gwt.validation.rebind - gwt-user-2.4.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0 - PatientCare
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt - gwt-user-2.4.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0 - PatientCare
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.model - gwt-user-2.4.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0 - PatientCare
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm - gwt-user-2.4.0.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0 - PatientCare
com.zzz.zzz.zzz.PatientCare.services.impl - src/main/java/server - PatientCare
com.sun.istack - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2 - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller - jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.4 - PatientCare
javax.persistence.spi - hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final - PatientCare
javax.xml.bind - jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.3 - PatientCare
org.codehaus.jackson - jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.8.5 - PatientCare
org.codehaus.jackson.impl - jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.8.5 - PatientCare
org.codehaus.jackson.io - jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.8.5 - PatientCare
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext - jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.8.5 - PatientCare
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser - jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.8.5 - PatientCare
org.fusesource.restygwt.client.dispatcher - restygwt-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\restygwt\restygwt\1.3-SNAPSHOT - PatientCare
org.hibernate.context - hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.6.10.Final - PatientCare
org.hibernate.stat - hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.6.10.Final - PatientCare
org.hibernate.util - hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.6.10.Final - PatientCare
org.hibernate.validator.internal.util - hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.3.0.Final - PatientCare
org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.scriptengine - hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.3.0.Final - PatientCare
org.jboss.resteasy.client - resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.3.4.Final - PatientCare
org.jboss.resteasy.client.cache - resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.3.4.Final - PatientCare
org.jboss.resteasy.core - resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.3.4.Final - PatientCare
org.jboss.resteasy.spi - resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.3.4.Final - PatientCare
org.jboss.resteasy.util - resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar - C:\Users\SofiaVergara\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.3.4.Final - PatientCare
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find references in Project relies on method name, that's why it's not accurate. Try using Call Hierarchy.

Comment: In Neon call hierarchy seems broken for static methods as well. I have static methods that get called hundreds of times that have a completely empty call hierarchy.

Comment: Call-hierarchy is broken too.

Answer (score 11):

With get highlighted, hit Ctrl+Shift+G. It'll come up with a list of results in the search tab/window. It'll find all references within your workspace. It does it via proper references, and not a plain text search.

Comment: He used the References within Project which is something subtly different, and clearly isn't working as intended. I don't use References within Project personally, as there's no default keyboard mapping out of the box for Eclipse. Refs within workspace is a better option IMO. I know for a fact that References within Workspace works exactly as the OP requested. I use it every day.

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse Kepler you can configure the search to filter out all *Potential Matches* (when using *References* - *Workspace* / *Project* or *Hierarchy*. To activate the filter, click the small down-arrow at the right top of the *Search* view and activate the *Potential Matches* check-box.
[image]

Comment: which translates to "exclude Potential Matches". perfect! Thank You.

Comment: This old answer somehow helps to deal with the surprising fact that searching for references to private member in my source file returns ALL similarities in all workspace JARs, including javadoc matches. Even if "potential" results are hidden, "Find references" sifts through entire workspace, soo slow. "get()" method? "message" field? you're welcome. Does Eclipse know what private means? In 2020 - not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, if you have multiple methods of the same name, e.g., constructors of a class, all with the same name but different signature, for example, it can be a pain to find all callers of one of those constructors. A trick you can use is to comment out the one you are investigating, and build. The compiler will then tell you all the places it is unable to find that signature, and hence these are exactly all the places that are trying to call that method with that name and that particular signature.

Comment: This is how I am doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse continues to have a bug, where Search->References->Workspace does not find method references.

I'm using this Eclipse:
Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33218884)